# Storing data received from an api call in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have checked many links and found that AsyncStorage is the best way to store any data but it is a persistent way. I just need to know if there is any other way to store session data which can should be available for a particular session like when a user logs in to my app.

In my use case, the user logs in with credentials and then we need user specific data to be displayed anywhere we need, like other screens. Any other way apart from Asyn Storage should I be using?

Comment: first question, are you using redux? i can suggest either redux or non redux way

Comment: means you are using redux right?

Comment: not using redux

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution for react native not using redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you are not using redux you can either use Asyncstorage or sqlite or realm. 
I would still prefer using Async storage as its persistant.

So what your problem statement looks like is a global value which can be displayed all over the app based on user session.

So when a user logins, you can set the Asyncstorage as

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
```

and when you want to retrieve :

```
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
```

and suppose when the user logs out so you want to delete the async storage value as thats related with that user, you simply call the below on logout :

```
await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@storage_Key')
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: That means Asyncstorage is the best way in my case. Thanks!

Comment: but where do i put it in my code please check once = > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124183/how-to-store-api-data-in-app-after-login-into-an-app-and-use-it-after-in-another

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend libraries react-native-keychain, realm or sqllite

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain

https://realm.io/products/realm-database

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

I hope the following article will help you to learn about these libraries and alternatives.

https://www.simform.com/react-native-database-selection-guide/

Hope this will help.